# Marking a style as not important

Tags: html, css

Is there any way of marking a style as **not** important - i.e. it **should** be overridden by any other overlapping styles.

I generate a report in html. At the bottom are two buttons, a *Go back* and a *Print* button. These buttons are removed when printing by linking to a *print.css* that contains a `{ display: none; }`. The buttons appear normally when displayed by the web service because the *normal.css* file defines a style for the buttons.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../normal.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../print.css" type="text/css" media="print">
```

I want to be able to e-mail the report as an html file and have the buttons also disappear when displayed in isolation. Obviously the *print.css* will not be present and n'or will *normal.css* file so I need an inline style that only takes effect when the style is **not** defined elsewhere.

```
.bottomButtons { display: none NOT !important; }
```

[This](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/guide/w3c_guide/dom_guide/html_priorities_css.htm) suggests that inline styles will always override linked styles. I hope that can be worked around somehow.

The style I want to override me (the one in the *normal.css* file) reads:

```
tr.bottomButtons
{
    background-color:#48C;
    color:#FFF;
    height:30px;
    valign:middle;
    font-weight:700;
}
```

I am not able to change the style in the *normal.css* file.

Comment: `!important` can even override inline style, so looks like you want some way to make inline style override `!important`?

Comment: @KingKing - I want the override to go the other way - I want my inline `display: none` to ONLY happen when no other `bottomButton` style exists. When `normal.css` is present I want **its** style to be used instead of mine.

Comment: KingKing is correct... This is one of those cases where you need to apply !important (which should always be done caredully!) You will need to apply `display: table-cell !important` to `tr.bottomButtons` in normal.css to achieve your goal. It's the only way a style in a stylesheet will override an inline style.

Comment: as I understand in fact the style in `normal.css` does not explicitly set `display` to anything else, otherwise it would override your style `.bottomButtons { display: none;}` (I suppose you have control over this, so no use of `!important` here).

Comment: Maybe you should use Media Queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries ?

Comment: @Volvox - That would have been perfect but I cannot find an appropriate query that would detect the absence of css files.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon - Sorry i didn't understood your question before. I don't think it is possible to do what you need with such limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the default style required for email as inline style.Then override using `!important` in the stylesheets print and normal.

html

```
<div id = "somediv" style = "background:red;"></div>
```

css

```
#somediv{
background:green!important;
}
```

When the css files are present the `#somediv` will have background color green and when they are not available color will be red

Comment: Sadly - *I am not able to change the style in the normal.css file.*

Comment: Could you explain me the reason pls.

Comment: I am writing an html report that makes use of existing css (in other project) to present a common look to all reports. However reports can be e-mailed and I want them to still look fair when the css is not present. I would like to place styles in the html of the report that are overridden by the project css.